# How to change a map's memory resource

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having trouble changing the memory resource of a map in my custom container.
It seems I can neither change the allocator of the map, nor create a new map with the custom memory resource.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <map>


using Map = std::pmr::map<const std::string, int>;

class custom_resource : public std::pmr::memory_resource {

    public:

    void* do_allocate(std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment) override {
        std::cout << "Using custom resource" << std::endl;
        return std::pmr::get_default_resource()->allocate(bytes, alignment);
    }

    void do_deallocate(void* p, std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment) override {
    }

    bool do_is_equal(const std::pmr::memory_resource& other) const noexcept override {
        return false;    
    }
};

struct MyContainer {

  void Reset(std::pmr::memory_resource &resource)
  {
      map_ = Map{&resource};
  }

  void AddItem(std::string k) {
      map_[k] = 1;
  }

    std::pmr::memory_resource* default_resource = std::pmr::get_default_resource();
    // custom_resource custom{}; // uncomment this and next line to see it work
    // Map map_{&custom};
    Map map_{default_resource};
};


int main() {

    MyContainer container{};
    container.AddItem("a"); // no output expected

    custom_resource custom{};
    container.Reset(custom);

    container.AddItem("b"); // output expected

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aVMuw6

How can I reset the container at runtime such that the custom memory resource is used to allocate items in the map?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a container's Allocator after it has been constructed. And even `polymorphic_allocator`'s memory resource cannot be changed after it has been constructed. So what you want isn't really doable; you are expected to know what memory resource your container will use at the time of its construction and that is the allocator+resource that it will use until its destruction.

There are circumstances that would allow you to copy/move/swap a new allocator into a container, but `polymorphic_allocator` disallows all of them.

Comment: Thanks, I accept that I cannot change it after construction. But I can't even seem to get a new one constructed with a new resource. I guess because the `= Map{&resource}` calls the assignment copy constructor or something like that? If I change the map to be a `unique_ptr` then I get it to work.